# How to solve the recurrence $T(n) = T(n − 2) + 1/\lg n$

Tags: summation, logarithms, recurrence-relations

while solving this question, I use the iteration method, which comes to
$$
T(n) = T(1) + \frac{1}{\lg n} + \frac{1}{\lg (n-2)}
            + \ldots + \frac{1}{\lg \left(n - 2^{k-1}\right)}.
$$
I really have no idea to get the summation of those lg.

[here is the summation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HROy9.png)

Can anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $n=2m$, you have
$$
\begin{split}
T(n) &= T(n-2) + \frac{1}{\lg n}\\
     &= T(n-4) + \frac{1}{\lg n} + \frac{1}{\lg (n-2)} \\
     &\ldots\\
     &= T(0) + \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{\lg (2k)}.
\end{split}
$$

If $n$ is odd, the last condition uses $T(1)$ and a slightly different summation...

I don't think there is a nice closed form for the sum, because
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\lg(2x)} = \frac{\ln(2)}{2} \textrm{li}(2x) + C,
$$
where $\textrm{li}(x)$ denotes the logarithmic integral function...